# Problem in writing german text on Image using python and PIL

Tags: image, python-2.7, text, unicode, python-imaging-library

I want to read a text file and extract text from it which is in German and write it on a png image using PIL and python 2.7 but when writing to image using .text() I get unknown text whenever Ü or some foreign character comes. I have used arialunicodems.ttf for font.

Firstly, I was extracting text from image using Microsoft azure cognitive vision and using .encode('utf-8') on each word and combining words to make a sentence in English and then converting to German using mtranslate library of python. Then I used arialunicodems.ttf as font and used .text() function of PIL Image to draw text on png. It was drawing properly for German, Chinese, hindi etc. But then I wanted to add a functionality for the user to be able to change the translated text if it was not correctly translated. For that, I saved the original text and translated text in a .txt file and display the content of the txt file to user where user changes it if needed and the changed text is again saved to txt file. Then using another python program, I added text to the image. But, this time the text is coming gibberish whenever its Ü, it draws Ã☐ on the image. For hindi, its all gibberish. What could be the problem?

Working code:
part where I was concatenating words to make a sentence(saved in variable text).

```py
for word in word_infos:
                bbox = [int(num) for num in word["boundingBox"].split(",")]
                if bbox[0]>=x and bbox[1]>=y and bbox[0]+bbox[2]<=x+w and bbox[1]+bbox[3]<=y+h:
                    text = text+word["text"].encode('utf-8')+" "
```

part where I was writing the text to image

```py
im = Image.open("check.png")
d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
helvetica = ImageFont.truetype("arialunicodems.ttf",10)
d.text((x,y), mtranslate.translate(text, sys.argv[3], sys.argv[2]), font=helvetica, fill=(0,0,0))
```

Not working code:
Part where I was saving the extracted text to txt file

```py
for word in word_infos:
                bbox = [int(num) for num in word["boundingBox"].split(",")]
                if bbox[0]>=x and bbox[1]>=y and bbox[0]+bbox[2]<=x+w and bbox[1]+bbox[3]<=y+h:
                    text = text+word["text"].encode('utf-8')+" "
file.write("orignaltext:"+text+"\n")
```

part where I was extracting text from txt file and writing on image

```py
im = Image.open("check.png")
d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
file2 = open("1.txt","r")
printframe = file2.readlines()
#j and traceorig is defined to extract text in loop
orig = printframe[j*6+3][traceorig:len(printframe[j*6+3])-1].encode('utf-8')
#xstr,ystr,r,g,b are extracted from image
d.text((int(xstr),int(ystr)), mtranslate.translate(orig,"de","en").encode('utf-8'), font=helvetica, fill=(int(r), int(g), int(b)))
```

For "Overview" in english, I want
In german: Überblick
In hindi: अवलोकन
In updated code, when I print on terminal, it prints correctly but on image it writes
In german: Ã☐berblick
In hindi: Not able to find characters, please see the image link [Hindi translated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqhRc.png).

**Update 1:**

A sample code to generate similar result

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
#file has only one line with text "Überblick"
file1 = open("write.txt","w+")
file1.write("Überblick")
file1.close()
file2 = open("write.txt","r")
content = file2.readlines()
file2.close()
img = np.zeros((300,300,1), np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite("stack.png",img)
im = Image.open("stack.png")
d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
helvetica = ImageFont.truetype("arialunicodems.ttf",50)
d.text((0,100), content[0].encode('utf-8'), font=helvetica, fill="white")
im.save("processed.png")
os.remove("stack.png")
```

See the processed.png for the output. [arialunicodems.ttf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10CAR7a292_AtAy4km-9im7PljswqFbdn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your question raises many more questions. If you are writing a new program, why write it in Python 2 when Python 3 which has significantly better Unicode handling has already been out for 11 years? Is your question actually about reading Unicode text files, or about writing Unicode text files, or about writing Unicode text on images?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Firstly, there is some module which only supports python 2 so using python 2. Secondly, my question is actually about writing unicode text on images using PIL.

Comment: So, in order to show a **Minimum Complete Verifiable Example**, you would need some code, with relevant `import` statements, that opens an image, or creates an empty black image and then writes a Unicode string on the image...

Comment: @MarkSetchell See the code I added in the question. Hope this works :)

Comment: If you remove all the unnecessary stuff and make a **Minimal** example, it works fine if you use `d.text((0,100), "Überblick", font=helvetica, fill="white") `

Comment: @MarkSetchell It says SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file stack.py on line 11, when I remove everything but when I add #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- the result is same as earlier. How did you generate the desired result?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I figured it out. The way you said to use does not work in python 2.x. To use it in python 2.x, it should be like ```python d.text((0,100), u'Überblick', font=helvetica, fill="white")``` or ```python d.text((0,100), unicode("Überblick"), font=helvetica, fill="white")```. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out myself. Anyone with a problem of writing unicode text on image using Python 2.x and PIL, first read [this link](https://learn.rmotr.com/python/understanding-unicode-in-python/strings-and-unicode/unicode-in-python). It's very informative about text encoding in different versions of python.
The answer is to use unicode().
Remove .encode('utf-8') and make it like:

```py
d.text((0,100), unicode(content[0]), font=helvetica, fill="white")
```

unicode() is to convert any string to unicode string similar to str() converts to a string.
Hope this helps someone in need.